# Javascript Facebook SDK DEBUG automatically

Tags: javascript, facebook, debugging, sdk

On my website I generate og:image automatically and using :

```
 $('meta[name=og\\:image]').attr('content', data.img);
```

Data.img is generated  image by PHP ;
When Client share content automatically,  og:image is right link, but it cannot debug faster and first share is without content, so I am trying to debug the link automatically with javascript, so when user generate the image, javascript will debug it and when client clicks share it will show correct image.
right now, I am trying like that :

```
 testing =  "https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://examplewebsite.com/test.php?dc="+data.code;

                                    FB.api(
                      '/',
                      'POST',
                      {"scrape":"true","id":testing},
                      function(response) {
                          // Insert your code here
                          console.log("requested:"+testing );

                      }
                    );
```

I also tried DEBUG link of the facebook URL , but no sucess, is there any other way to debug link ?
Note:  Share works finally after trying 2-3 times, then it shows correct image. But if I do javsacript wich do this tries ( Debug) Then it will works) Any idea?

Comment: Facebook don't execute Javascript when scraping your page.

Comment: So what possibilities I have to improve Speed of debugging the website link? Since it does not works at first-second share

Comment: Which URL are you sharing?

Comment: [link](http://myapps123.com/test.php?test=tests)  Click here  then click "ტესტის დაწყება"   then approve  permissions to app and when Image generated click "გააზიარე" 
anyway Example url  : 
[example] (http://myapps123.com/test.php?dc=4trQytfe4KOL197g0tjMp93R26Trqp2ei@6qmp2WsJ6bm5ipnp@glq@koZHLtqWbm5ysoaCknamin6ObrZPP2aK9zt/UyZmvys3a587c09vi2dKR2ueqsN3O4NzVi7ja2uHM19rR49CRmdSjnZ2ljd3Q2O2nm6ORmeLXzNLep7DdzuDc1Yu42trhzNfa0ePQkZnT18zS3qetzNvi0Ymtxtvi18zY4ePS186ljdvQ2MKxo5@Y)

Comment: I would guess og:image is not set the first time Facebook scrapes the URL

Comment: When we generate the LINK if we go on that link og:image is shows correct image ,  so how it is not set?

Comment: ...because it is set with javascript? the very first comment here should tell you why it does not work.

Comment: This code that I posted is just few, however, when the image creating process is, it's generating image and link, javascript swaps the  og:image url ,  so I can see that in the source code, So fb should see that og:image;

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching